# Visual C#: Metro app change background (Programmatically)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is there a function in C# that changes the background of the current page (or grid)?

C#:

```
int hourOfDay = DateTime.Now.Hour;
if(hourOfDay <= 12 && hourOfDay >= 18) {
    /* Set background to afternoon_bg.jpg
     * 
     * In XAML:
     * <Grid.Background>
     *     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/afternoon_bg.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
     * </Grid.Background> */
}
if(hourOfDay <= 6 && hourOfDay >= 12) {
    /* Set background to morning_bg.jpg
     * 
     * In XAML:
     * <Grid.Background>
     *     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/morning_bg.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
     * </Grid.Background> */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutRoot` is your grid name, you can set background like this:

```
    int hourOfDay = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
    if(hourOfDay >= 12 && hourOfDay < 18) {
        ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage( new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/afternoon_bg.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else if (hourOfDay >= 6 && hourOfDay < 12)
    {
        ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/morning_bg.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }
    LayoutRoot.Background = ib;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one problem left - Visual Studio gives me the error that I can't convert a `BitmapImage` into an `ImageSource`. Did I forgot something?

Comment: I have no error for that code. please check you code if you lose sth or sth coded wrong.

Comment: I checked my code for errors, but I couldn't find any. I wrote this code in a `void`, also I didn't import `LayoutRoot`, because I can't find the namespace, can you please post it?.

Comment: LayoutRoot is the name of your grid.the root grid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage( new Uri(@"\Pictures\profile.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
grd.Background = ib;
```

`grd` is your grid name.